# I-Series Daily Backup

Tags: tapedrive, lto-4

I have just purchased a new tape drive that is not a library system.  (Long story)  It is a LTO4 and we would like to back up 2 days on one tape.  Is this possible?  The new system we ordered will not allow us to add our older tape drive without massive costs.

Answer (score 2):

LTO4 is rated at 800GB per cartridge.

You can get a rough approximation of your backup size by checking the ASP used with the `WRKSYSSTS` command:

```
System ASP . . . . . . . :     1515 G
% system ASP used  . . . :    79.9265
```

The machine I pulled that information from performs a full backup nightly to LTO4.

Whatever backup method you use be sure to specify `ENDOPT(*LEAVE)`.  When you are ready to eject the tape just use the `CHKTAP DEV(...) ENDOPT(*UNLOAD)` command.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either run two different CL programs to run your backups or somehow determine which day you don't want to eject the tape. At least that is how I understand it. I usually just do one tape per day anyway.